# Problema con consulta en mysql

Tags: mysql

Tengo una situacion y necesito que alguien me ayude con una consulta.Tengo 2 tablas,una que se llama Usuario(esta guarda todos los usuarios que se loguean en el sistema,tanto doctores como pacientes) y otra Doctor-Paciente con 2 campos,uno es el id del paciente y el otro el de su doctor correspondiente.

Lo que necesito es una consulta que me muestre el nombre(se encuentra en la tabla Usuario) de todos los pacientes de un doctor dado(es el que se encuentre actualmente logueado en el sistema)

Comment: añade la estrcutura de las tablas involucradas asi como las queries que haz tratado hasta el momento

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno faltan varios datos pero intuiré que es una base de datos de sql. Por lo que la consulta se medio generaliza, (solo traducela a la forma correcta segun sea el caso) . (SQLServer, MySQL, SQLite, posgress, etc).

```
SELECT Usuario.Nombre, Doctor.Nombre, Usuario.Id, Doctor.id 
FROM Usuarios 
JOIN Doctores 
ON Usuario.Id = Doctor.Id
WHERE Doctor.Id = $variable
```

Solo le tienes que pasar la variable del doctor que esta logeado, esto te traerá todas las coincidencias que cumplan con:

```
Doctor.Id = $variable
```

y que

```
Usuario.Id = Doctor.ID
```

Comment: no deberías estar respondiendo a una pregunta que ni siquiera muestra ni la query ni las tablas involucradas, ni los nombres de las columnas por que ahorita lo unico que estas haciendo es adivinar, -1

Comment: Desde mi punto de vista se entiende su pregunta. Tal vez no sabe como formular un JOIN

Comment: deberías de leer el [tour] en la comunidad se exige una pregunta de calidad, para responderla como se va a entender si no muestra ni las tablas, por favor ayuda a mantener la calidad del sitio evitando responder preguntas mal planteadas o te lloverán los votos de -1

Comment: Hola Alberto, no es cuestion de entender la pregunta si no que Jesús tiene que mostrar más informacion de su situacion actual y del error o problema concreto que tiene. Es mejor esperar a esa informacion antes de responder. Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

captura el id del doctor .. al momento de buscar el listado de sus pacientes el ejemplo seria asi..

```
SELECT * FROM doc_pacientes inner join personas on persona_id = doc_pacientes.fk_persona WHERE doc_paciente.id = $docLogueado
```

$doc_logueado sera tu variable que almacena el id del doctor y listo.. agrupas por el id del doctor.. y te traera 1solo doctor y lo demas en pacientes :).. o solo q te traiga la informacion del paciente

Comment: lo mismo que al compañero de la otra respuesta, no respondas preguntas tan mal planteadas, que no agregan ni las tablas ni la query intentada; no sabemos que es lo que no sabe hacer a ciencia exacta por favor ayudanos a mantener el nivel